# Android some TextView's id to array and fetch from that to assign text

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to save some `TextView` id's to array and fetch that with `for loop` to assign text. or example:

```
String[] other_stuff_items = other_soft.split(";");
int[] tvs ={
        R.id.tv_other_stuff_one,
        R.id.tv_other_stuff_two,
        R.id.tv_other_stuff_three
};
int[] ivs ={
        R.id.ix_other_stuff_one,
        R.id.ix_other_stuff_two,
        R.id.ix_other_stuff_three
};
```

after saving TextView id's to array I'm trying to get array items with `for loop`

```
for( int i=0; i>other_stuff_items.length; i++){
    tvs[i].setText(items_one[0]);
    ivs[i].setText(items_one[1]);
}
```

**In this above section, I get error for `.setText()` and get widgets from array** how to resolve this problem? thanks

Comment: `setText` stands for `TextView`not for int array. You must use `TextView` array.

Comment: setText() is TextView properties not int so you can not directly use with have to find TextView from int id and then try to use setText().

Comment: what error are you getting, when using .setText()? @mahdi

Comment: @DroidWorm Narendra problem resolve by `sshashank124` topic sir.

Comment: Okay, thats great (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first find the `View`s:

```
Textview tv;

for( int i=0; i>other_stuff_items.length; i++){
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(tvs[i]);
    tv.setText(items_one[0]);
    // do the same thing for the ivs stuff
}
```